# How to change number of arcs in an inductor schematics?

Tags: circuitikz

Since Czech standards (ČSN) do not accept the IEC standards, I have to draw an inductor with only 3 arcs. Is there any solution for `CircuiTikZ`? I have already saw some papers typsetted with `LaTeX` using `CircuiTikZ`, so I am sure, there is way how to tackle with it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, always add a MWE (Minimal Working Example) of your problem to illustrate what you already have got and to keep the burden from us in doing all the work for your.  In your special case, a sketch of circuit would be helpful.

Comment: See recent version of `circuitikz` (Version 0.8 (2017-03-08)). There are some novelties also for inductors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that you can specify the number of coils with the american inductor and the cute inductor.  The bad news is that there is a bug in the american inductor code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/cuteinductor/coils=3}
\ctikzset{bipoles/americaninductor/coils=3}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vcuteinductor/coils=3}% variable
\ctikzset{bipoles/vamericaninductor/coils=3}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[cute inductor] (2,0)
      (0,1) to[american inductor] (2,1)
      (0,2) to[variable cute inductor] (2,2)
      (0,3) to[variable american inductor] (2,3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Here is the bug fix for the american inductor:

```
\makeatletter
%% american inductor

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/height 2}}{americaninductor}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/width}}{
    \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth} 
    \pgftransformationadjustments
    \advance \pgf@circ@res@step by \pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment\pgflinewidth
    \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/coils}
    \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by 2
    \pgf@circ@res@other = \ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/coil height}\pgf@circ@Rlen

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*0.5*\pgflinewidth}{-\pgfverticaltransformationadjustment*0.4*\pgfstartlinewidth}}%correct value would be 0.5 but arcs are not really flat, therefore 0.4 is better is (almost) all cases
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\ctikzvalof{bipoles/americaninductor/coils}}
    {\pgfpatharc{180}{0}{\pgf@circ@res@step and \pgf@circ@res@other}}
    \pgfsetbuttcap
    \pgfsetbeveljoin
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The mentioned bug is already fixed since the latest release 0.8 last week :)